# cannot change background during game play gamemaker?

Tags: game-maker

I use this on event create to change background during game play. But won't change the background, any idea?

```
seconds = current_second;

if seconds < 30
{
    background_index[0] = background0;
    background_visible[0] = true;
}

if seconds > 30
{
    background_index[5] = background5;
    background_visible[5] = true;
}

// Set background
background_hspeed[0] = -2;
background_hspeed[5] = -2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your goal, so a few examples:

**Example 1.**

Create event:

```
background_index[0] = background0;
background_index[1] = background1;
```

Step event:

```
seconds = current_second;

if seconds < 30
{
    background_visible[0] = true;
    background_visible[1] = false;
}
else 
{
    background_visible[0] = false;
    background_visible[1] = true;
}
```

**Example 2.** Same, but using alarm

Create event:

```
background_index[0] = background0;
background_index[1] = background1;

event_perform(ev_alarm, 0);
```

Alarm 0 event:

```
seconds = current_second;

if seconds < 30
{
    background_visible[0] = true;
    background_visible[1] = false;
}
else 
{
    background_visible[0] = false;
    background_visible[1] = true;
}

alarm[0] = room_speed * 30;
```

**Example 3.** Other idea...

Create event:

```
background_index[0] = background0;
background_index[1] = background1;
background_visible[0] = true;
background_visible[1] = true;

event_perform(ev_alarm, 0);
```

Alarm 0 event:

```
seconds = current_second;

if seconds < 30
{
    background_index[0] = background0;
    background_index[1] = background1;
}
else 
{
    background_index[0] = background1;
    background_index[1] = background0;
}

background_x[0] = 0;
background_x[1] = 0;
background_hspeed[0] = 0;
background_hspeed[1] = -2;

alarm[0] = room_speed * 30;
```

If you need to change backgrounds many times then you need use `step` event or alarms, because `create` event does it only once. Also when you use scrolling, you need remember that after some time `x` position of the background will be outside a screen, so you can't see background (except cases when your background is tiled).

Comment: "because create event do only once" now it make sense.